# Obtain Pandas series index levels using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas series with 2 levels (as shown in the first image). I want to use a for loop to print the first level (.index.levels[0]) of each entry. i.e the output I am looking for should be (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,....). Since the first month has 9 entries followed by 2 which should also have 9 entries and then 3 for the third month and so on.

I have written the following code below, but instead of getting (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,....), I end up with, "int64Index([1,2,3,4,5,6, .....],dtypes = 'int64',name = 'month'): repeated as shown in the second image. Any ideas how to get the month for each entry?

```
for i in df_postMonMean:
    print(df_postMonMean[df_postMonMean == i].index.levels[0])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you want [`df.index.get_level_values('month')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2011', 1],
                   ['1', '2012', 2],
                   ['1', '2013', 3],
                   ['2', '2011', 1],
                   ['2', '2012', 4],
                   ['2', '2013', 5],
                   ['3', '2011', 5],
                   ['3', '2012', 5],],
                  columns=['month','year','value']).set_index(['month','year'])

print(df)

print(df.index.get_level_values(0))
```

Output:

```
            value
month year       
1     2011      1
      2012      2
      2013      3
2     2011      1
      2012      4
      2013      5
3     2011      5
      2012      5
Index(['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3'], dtype='object', name='month')
```

You can also use `df.index.get_level_values('month')`